# Chrome extension to click a button once 'Enter' is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, browser-extension

I am using some unique chat service that is 100% suitable with my business needs.
However, the only flaw in it is that it lacks the most basic feature of chat applications - sending a message via the 'Enter' button.

I was wondering whether it'd be possible to develop some Chrome extension (you're welcome to suggest other method if there are ones) - that once the user clicks the 'Enter' button the native 'Send' button within the website will be clicked, and the chat text box will be re-focused.

Is it possible? Can one please suggest how this should be approached?
Much appreciated!

This is the HTML code of the button within the chat window

```
<button class="btn button button-md button-clear button-clear-md" clear="" icon-only="" ion-button="" ng-reflect-clear="" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s;"><span class="button-inner">
                          <ion-icon name="send" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-md-send" aria-label="send" ng-reflect-name="send"></ion-icon>
                        </span><div class="button-effect"></div></button>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, use standard DOM events and methods in a `content script`.

Comment: woxxom thanks for the reply. Can you share some example project I can use as a reference?